# Cannot access published story after Permission Rebuild

Tags: php, drupal, permissions, drupal-7

So yeah, the issue is there are some articles, (very old one 2015~), which anonymous users can not access after i've done rebuilding permissions.

New content does not seem to be affected though. One solution I can do (after researching) is to re-save these articles, BUT I think i can not keep doing this because there are a lot of articles., im telling more than 100K

Is there a better way to resolve this?

PS: I confirm that the permission is set correctly for anonymous users to see published content.

Answer (score 0):

We can only speculate what happen, without diving into your custom code or checking at the list of contrib modules that you are using it is almost impossible to detect where the issue is. If you are sure that re-save makes the problem go away, add views bulk operation module - which will allow you to select all nodes in one go than select publish bulk operation (this will trigger node save). You can narrow down and add filters to your admin/content view to show only older nodes (around 10k nodes takes 15 mins to resave - regular node article) - this will not bring down your site or slow it down since it's bulk operation and you can always do this during the night when there are few users on the site... Do a db backup before, resave nodes on live so the users can access nodes, import the database on your local machine and peacefully (since live is working) hunt down the source of the issue.